# What are units in neural network (backpropagation algorithm)

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, classification, backpropagation

Please help me to understand unit thing in neuron networks. From the book I understood that a unit in input layer represents an attribute of training tuple. However, it is left unclear, how exactly it does.

Here is the diagram:
[image]

There are two "thinking paths" about the input units. The first it could could be that **X1** stands for **attr1**, **X2** stands for **attr2**... Otherwise, it could be that **X1**, **X2**, and **X3** represent **attr1**, but **X1** stands for **Value.VALUE_ONE**, ... , **X3** stands for **Value.VALUE_THREE**. So in least case, if **attr1 = Value.VALUE_TWO** then it weighted and fed simultaneously to a second layer.

```java
public class Tuple
{
  private Value attr1
  private Value attr2
  private Value attr3
}

public enum Value
{
  VALUE_ONE,
  VALUE_TWO,
  VALUE_THREE
}
```

The second question is about hidden layer units. How it is decided how much units it shall be in hidden layer, and what they represent in the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "units" are just floating point values.

All computations happening there are vector multiplications, and thus can be parallelized well using matrix multiplications and GPU hardware.

The general computation looks like this:

```
double v phi(double[] x, double[] w, double theta) {
  double sum = theta;
  for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    sum += x[i] * w[i];
  return tanh(sum);
}
```

except that you don't want to do this in Java code yourself. You want to do this on a GPU in a parallelized way, because this will be 100x faster.

Comment: As I understood the x[] is a numeric representation of tuple attributes, and w[] is a weight of its connections, but I still dont realize how to derive the x[i] from the tuple attribute.

Comment: It is assumed that the input data is numeric. You can try to use encodings such as male=0, female=1.

Comment: That makes sense, so the attributes (x[]) have to be ordinal. and the number of units in input layer is equal to the number of attributes has a tuple.  However, still unclear the units of hidden layer, how shall I define the number of units there. On the diagram in the book I use, hidden layer has a smaller amount of units, and it dosent make sense.

Comment: Depends on your domain. It's common to have fewer hidden units in each level than in the input layer, because you want *abstraction*. But NNs seem to work best when applied to e.g. image data that has a much higher dimensionality than necessary.